# Receiving error from requests.get "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"

Tags: python, json, flask

I am trying to receive data from a JSON API using Python and Flask. However, whenever I check to see if the request is returning the right data, I receive this error message, "**json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**"

Here is how my code looks:

```
state = request.args['testing-state']
    url = f'https://covid-19-testing.github.io/locations/{state}/complete.json'
    res = requests.get(url)
```

My server is receiving data from a form containing the state variable contents.

Comment: first check `print( res.text )` - maybe you get message as normal HTML. You could also check `print( url )` to see if you created correct url - and then you can test it directly in web browser to see what you get from server - maybe it sends something different then JSON data.

Comment: I tested your url with `texas` and it gives JSON data but for `Texas` it give error 404 - so maybe you have to change `state` to `lower()`. And it only shows that you should use `print( url )` to see what url you try to use.

Comment: You have been a great help. I used print(url) found out that I was receiving a 404 page. I then used the lower() method on my state variable and everything works perfectly now :)